# Display array object in Alert

Tags: arrays, react-native, alert

I am trying to display all my array item properties within the Alert screen when a button is pressed. My problem is getting the item properties to be displayed in the alert pop up.

```
 Alert.alert(
     'Country: ', item.country,
     'Gas: ', item.gasService,
     'Size: ', item.size,

   );
```

This displays the country correctly but nothing else.
I want to display all the items properties in the alert screen but I cannot get it to work at all.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use + to concatenate items, and \n to display them on separate lines.

```
Alert.alert( 'Country: ' + item.country + "\n" + 
     'Gas: ' + item.gasService + "\n" +
     'Size: ' + item.size  + "\n"
   );
```